# Is it possible to get a single range selector instead of two in highcharts?

Tags: php, highcharts

I have a requirement of single slider type range selector to get the selected value from the graph. I saw highcharts but it consists two selector. Is it possible to have single selector instead of two?

This is the diagram.

> |100____90____80____70____60_____50_____40_____30_____20______10
>   |**_____________________________**||**__________________________________**

I am providing a link : http://webmagical.com/wmsprojects/graph/slider.jpg

Comment: Do you mean handles in the bottom navigator? If yes, unfortunatley you cannot disable it.

Comment: I did not mean to say the bottom navigator. I want a single selector instead of the left and right range selectors.

Comment: Please attach your mockup

Comment: I wanted to post an image to show my requirement but i don't have that reputation to post an image. So, i am trying to clear my view as much as i can. I have a graph of buyer(y axis) and price(x axis) and there will be a single slider that indicates the price when it slides from left to right or right to left.

Comment: So please update anywahere, and attach link because it is not clear for me.

Comment: Hi Sebastian Bochan, i have updated my post with a link.

Comment: In when you move slider range increases or move ?

Comment: The X axis shows the range of prices that decreases from (0,0) to end. Now if an user slides the bar, i want to grab the range value. I think you understand my requirement.

Comment: In the highscharts you can use setExtremes/afterSetExtremes events to control slider. Other solition is using a jquery UI slider, then prepare your own javascript solution to slide, and call setExtremes on the chart.